# NS Unknown Key exception with outlets connected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm getting a "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" when I connect outlets to UI textfield, which can only be fixed when I disconnect the UI from the outlets.
Other answers do not work, since I don't see any ! errors when right-clicking the UI to check for outlet errors.
Code that I'm using: 
import Foundation
import Firebase
import UIKit 
class UserSignUp: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var gradient:CAGradientLayer?
       @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!

```
   @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

```
       addGradient()
       signUpButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
       email.delegate = self
       password.delegate = self
       passwordConfirm.delegate = self
   }

   @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {

       if password.text != passwordConfirm.text{
           let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
           let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

           alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
       else{
           Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in
               if error == nil {
                  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
               }
               else{
                   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                   alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
           }
       }
   }
   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
       return true
   }
   func addGradient() {
       gradient = CAGradientLayer()
       let startColor = UIColor(red: 3/255, green: 196/255, blue: 190/255, alpha: 1)
       let endColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
       gradient?.colors = [startColor.cgColor,endColor.cgColor]
       gradient?.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
       gradient?.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y:1)
       gradient?.frame = view.frame
       self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient!, at: 0)
   }
```

}

Comment: Just a minor note (it won't solve your problem): You don't need to import Foundation and UIKit, because UIKit includes Foundation already (Hold cmd and klick on UIKit -> Jump to definition and you will see it)

Comment: Right click on your VC in Interface Builder and check that all Outlets/Action are named the same as in your view controller class, and that there are no duplicates.  Make sure your VC in IB has the correct class.  Do a clean CMD+OPT+SHFT K.   If it still isn't working post a screen shot of your connections in IB.

Comment: The exception message will tell you what is wrong; most likely you haven't set the custom class for the viewcontroller in the storyboard scene.  Edit your question to include the full exception message